# Using async Pyramid with aiozmq and websockets

Tags: websocket, zeromq, pyramid, python-asyncio

I'm trying to create a Pyramid application made of two processes:

- a "classic", synchronous Pyramid application, which is a CMS
- another asynchronous application, also based on Pyramid. But this application is run in a different process by Gunicorn using aiopyramid.

WebSockets base management is OK.

Now, I need to implement a ZeroMQ server which will be used to communicate with the CMS in a request/reply mode: on specific events, the CMS will send a ZeroMQ message which will be checked and new messages will be sent to connected WebSockets.

My problem actually is that ZeroMQ messages are correctly handled, but WebSockets messages are never sent!

This is how messages are handled:

```
    class MyHandler(object):
        def __init__(self, stream):
            self.stream = stream

        def __call__(self, message):
            self.stream.write((json.dumps({'status': "OK"}).encode(),))
            for user in users:
                user.ws.send(message)
            print("Message sent...")

    def init_zmq_handler():
        stream = yield from aiozmq.create_zmq_stream(zmq.REP,
                                                 bind='tcp://0.0.0.0:5580')
        stream.transport._protocol.msg_received = MyHandler(stream)
```

"init_zmq_handler" is called during the Pyramid application startup process.
"users" is a list of connected WebSockets; the same list is used in a WebSockets view without problem.

Actually, the "Message sent..." message is displayed but WebSockets messages are not sent!
It's probably an asyncronous call problem but I'm don't have the habit to use them yet and I'm a little lost.
I've tried to declare somme of the functions as coroutines but then the ZeroMQ call is hanging and WebSockets messages are not sent either...

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Best regards,
Thierry

Comment: I never used your stack, but have you tried to move your print statement inside your `for user in users` loop? You could print `user.id` for example. A bit unrelated, but instead of printing, you should use logging.

Comment: "print" state ment is just hère for debugging purpose. In real code I use logging. I also tried to mové print inside user loop; message is printed but websockets messages are not sent..  :-/

Comment: I finally managed to make this work by using server to server Websockets insteam of ZeroMQ...